Debian unstable: can't install deborphan
When trying to install package deborphan on Debian unstable / sid I get the following error:
usr@hst ~ [100]> sudo apt install deborphan
Package deborphan is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Error: Package 'deborphan' has no installation candidate
usr@hst ~ [100]>

My apt is up-to-date and /etc/apt/sources.list has the following sources listed:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

On some other VM, with the same configuration, but with older packages database, deborphan is there and can be installed.
By searching the Debian package archive online, I found the package page which says that deborphan package in sid exists only for riscv64 architecture, and, unlike for other distributions, it is not available for other architectures.
How do I install deborphan package in sid?
Is it possible to use the stable version of the deborphan package, while staying on unstable / sid?

What happens if you try to install package orphaner?

If you go to Debian Tracker, you'll find that deborphan package has been removed from testing distribution.
Refer to this link
Here is a quote from that reference:

FYI: The status of the deborphan source package in Debian's testing
distribution has changed.
Previous version: 1.7.35   Current version:  (not in testing)
Hint: https://release.debian.org/britney/hints/auto-removals
# 1065310

Ref 2 from tracker.debian.com

This package is not in any development repository. This probably means
that the package has been removed (or has been renamed). Thus the
information here is of little interest ... the package is going to
disappear unless someone takes it over and reintroduces it.

